# re.fullmatch sql python telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I need an exact comparison with records from a database. I have a string data from db:

```
print(str(db.get_nicknames2(message.from_user.id)))
//[('123',), ('lopr',), ('hello',), ('imfamous2',), ('guy',)]
```

Does not work:

```
message = 'famous2'
info = str(db.get_nicknames2(message.from_user.id))
re.fullmatch(message,info)
//None
```

It works but i need to compare from db:

```
message = 'famous2'
info = 'famous2'
re.fullmatch(message,info)
//re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='imfamous2
```

Comment: `message` is a string, it doesn't have `from_user` property. What is `message.from_user.id` supposed to be? Did you mean `info = 'famous2'`?

Comment: `fullmatch()` only matches if the entire string matches the pattern. Use `re.search()` to search for the pattern anywhere.

Comment: Why are you converting into a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need `re` for this at all. Just loop over the `info` list instead of converting it to a string.

```
info = 'famous'
data = db.get_nicknames2(message.from_user.id)
nickname = None
# first look for exact match
for (nick,) in data:
    if info == nick:
        nickname = nick
        break
else:
    # not found, look for substring match
    for (nick,) in data:
        if info in nick:
            nickname = nick
            break
```

Comment: its work, but if i have nicknames = "imfamous" and "imfamous2", this code give me two records. I need an exact match thats why i tried to use fullmatch

Comment: But you want `famous` to match `imfamous2`, don't you? I don't see how it can do that and not have `imfamous` to match `imfamous2`.

Comment: Use `=` instead of `in` if you want an exact match of the whole word.

Comment: my goal is to check if the input nickname is in the database

Comment: please wait i will try

Comment: Your last example says that you want to return `imfamous2` when `message = 'famous2`.

Comment: yes!, only one record

Comment: But it doesn't match the whole word, so why is it returned?

Comment: If you only want the first match, break out of the loop when you find it.

Comment: Why not do this in the database query? `SELECT nickname FROM nicknames WHERE id = ? AND nickname = ?`

Comment: if i have info = 'famous', in database i have 'imfamous2', i return imfamous2, but i need return only famous if it exists

Comment: So you want the closest match?

Comment: Use two loops. First look for an exact match. If you don't find anything, do another loop to find a substring match.

Comment: how loop for an exact match?

Comment: barmar i'm sorry for my english. i want one exact match